# How can we (de)serialize data in jackson using SubtypeResolver.registerSubtypes(...) rather than annotations?

Tags: java, jackson

I have class structure as follows:

```
@JsonTypeName("0")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "statType")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class)
})
class Parent {
......
}
```

Now I want to keep the Parent in one project and the child in a separate dependent project. However, if I use the annotation I need the child type from the dependent project. SubtypeResolver.registerSubtypes seems to be the answer but I cannot find a good example of it being used. How to register subtypes of a specific parent class using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for `ObjectMapper.registerSubtypes()'?